# Powershell - find,copy,list out missing files

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell to help me find a list of files from a list created in CVS. I need it to search through a folder and its sub-folder. copy the files listed in the CVS and output the files that are not founded in the folder to a log.txt file.

I found this script listed below but I don't know how to get it to output a list of missing files into a log.txt.

```
$source      = "C:\Folder-A"
$destination = "C:\Folder-B"

$file_list = Get-Content "C:\Book1.csv" 

foreach ($file in $file_list){
    foreach($dir in (Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse)){
        if($file -eq $dir.name){
            if(-not(test-path "$destination\$file")){
                Copy-Item $dir.fullname -Destination $destination
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code relative to what you're trying to achieve:

1. Your '$dir' variable will actually be files and directories unless there are nothing in the tree structure besides directories (no files)
2. You're performing the copy way more times than you have to because of your double-loop and performing the copy on every conditional failure (if ($file -eq $dir.name))

test

```
$source      = "C:\Folder-A"
$destination = "C:\Folder-B"

# will be an array of values, from your code, appears to be an array of file name values alone
$file_list = Get-Content "C:\Book1.csv" 

# Return the FileSystemObjects (Files AND Directories), recursively
$FSOs = (Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse)

# Iterate through each entry in the desired list
foreach ($file in $file_list){

    # Create a string-based array of only the recurive files+directory names and see if our desired name-value is contained in it
    if(($FSOs | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -contains $file){

        # Check to see if it exists in the destination location and if not, copy it
        if(-not(test-path "$destination\$file")){
            Copy-Item $dir.fullname -Destination $destination
        }
    } else {  # For the values from the text-file that were not found in the directory structure, append them to a log file
        $file | Out-File 'NotFoundInDirectory.log' -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: This is strange, I try running the same script again but I change the content in my Book1.csv and it did not work. it just copies whatever content I have in the folder and just put it into my destination folder. no log file output also.

Comment: What's the new content of Book1.csv?

Comment: just image.jpg and some.txt files. Was just playing around with the script and notice it just grap everything in that source folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we need all files in the destination when we are done, and the file list is just a list of filenames with no path, we just pull the existing using recursive get-childitem then copy all files to the destination using -force -confirm:$false and diff the existing list with our file list. You will run into errors because you have no path information, and you run the risk of duplicates due to subfolders and -recursive. Instead, pull everything in real time, just like robocopy or rsync would do, and operate and take a record:

```
$source = "C:\Folder-A"
$destination = "C:\Folder-B"
$logfile="C:\logfile.csv"
$files=@()
$existinglist=(Get-ChildItem $destination -Recurse -erroraction silentlycontinue)
$file_list = (Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -erroraction silentlycontinue)

foreach ($file in $file_list){
    if ($existinglist.Name -contains $file.name){
        $filedestination=$existinglist |?{$_.name -like $file.name}
        Copy-Item $file.fullname -Destination $filedestination.fullname -force -confirm:$false
        $tempitem1=new-object pscustomobject
        add-member -InputObject $tempitem1 -NotePropertyName "filename" -NotePropertyValue $file
        add-member -inputobject $tempitem1 -NotePropertyName "existed" -NotePropertyValue $true
        $files+=$tempitem1
    }else{
        Copy-Item $file.fullname -Destination $destination -force -confirm:$false
        $tempitem1=New-Object pscustomobject
        add-member -InputObject $tempitem1 -NotePropertyName "filename" -NotePropertyValue $file
        add-member -InputObject $tempitem1 -NotePropertyName "existed" -NotePropertyValue $false
        $files+=$tempitem1
}

$files |export-csv -path $logfile -NoTypeInformation
```

I am assuming that this is for educational purposes as you are new to powershell and curious which is great, and why we have the answer and explanation with code. In production, we should be using robocopy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy or in *nix we go for rsync https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rsync. I hope this helps!